# Division with php

Tags: php

Im trying to get out an average value from a vote function.

```
<?php

    $file = file("textfile.txt");
    $textfil = file_get_contents("textfile.txt");
    $textfill = str_split($textfil);


    echo "Number of votes: " . count($textfill) . "<br>";
    $sum = 0;

    foreach ($textfill as $vote) {
        $sum = $sum + intval($vote);
    }
    echo "Average: " . $sum;
?>
```

Simple by substitute (+) with a (/), and even tried a (%). But still getting error message.
Would appreciate alot if anyone could help me out and tell me what im doing wrong.

/thanks

Comment: Also, average is sum/count, which means `$sum/count($textfill)` in your case. You should give an example of your `textfile.txt`.

Comment: Pls provide sample input from textfile.txt Why are you using str_split?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Edit

***Sidenote:*** Please read an explanation under ***"First answer given"*** further down below.

This version will take into account any blank lines in a file, if the content looks like:

```
1
2

3
// <- blank line
```

***Sidenote:*** Please provide a sample of your text file. A [`comment`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22637541/division-with-php#comment34475924_22637541) has already been given to that effect.

PHP

```
<?php
// first line not required
    // $file = file("textfile.txt");
$textfil = file_get_contents("textfile.txt");

$textfill = array_filter(array_map("trim", file("textfile.txt")), "strlen");

    echo "Number of votes: " . count($textfill) . "<br>";
    $sum = 0;

foreach ($textfill as $vote) {

    $sum += intval($vote);
}
$avg = $sum / count($textfill);

    echo "Average: " . $avg;
?>
```

---

### First answer given

Using the following in a text file: *(since no example of file content was given)*

5
5
5

IMPORTANT NOTE: There should not be a carriage return after the last entry.

produced

Number of votes: 5
Average: 3

which is false, since there are 3 entries in the text file.

[`explode()`](http://www.php.net/explode) should be used, and not [`str_split()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php)

The following using the same text file produced:

Number of votes: 3
Average: 5

which is correct. In simple mathematics, averages are done by adding all numbers then dividing them by how many numbers there are.

In this case it's 3 numbers (all 5's) added equals 15, divided by 3 is 5.

Sidenote: The first line is not required `$file = file("textfile2.txt");`

```
<?php
// first line not required
//  $file = file("textfile.txt");
    $textfil = file_get_contents("textfile.txt");

    $textfill = explode("\n", $textfil);

    echo "Number of votes: " . count($textfill) . "<br>";
    $sum = 0;

foreach ($textfill as $vote) {
    $sum += intval($vote);
}
$avg = $sum / count($textfill);
    echo "Average: " . $avg;
?>
```

---

**Footnotes:**

If the average comes out to 8.33333 and you would like it to be rounded off to `8`, use:

```
echo "Average: " . floor($avg);
```

If the average comes out to 8.33333 and would like it to be as `9` you would use:

```
echo "Average: " . ceil($avg);
```

---

- [`ceil()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php) function
- [`floor()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php) function

Comment: Thanks for answer!
Yes, I should have declared where this function would be used to. Its a rating system and it shows the average of #ofvotes with # total amount. Each vote is seperated by a dash.
Thanks for answer! It works fine! Though is it possible to add code so only whole numbers are shown? Because now its 4.01010919191<?

Comment: You're welcome. Yes it's possible. For example: If the average comes out to 8.33333 and you would like it to be 8, use `echo "Average: " . floor($avg);` and if you want 8.33333 to be as 9 you would do `echo "Average: " . ceil($avg);` @Winterwind

Comment: I have added it at the bottom of my answer for future reference under **Footnotes**. @Winterwind

Answer (score 0):

You may be mixing in stuff that can't be divided, like text, etc. I don't know what your text file looks like. intval may be having a problem with arrays. You may try:

```
 foreach ($textfill as $vote) {
   if(is_int($vote) {
     $sum += $vote;
   }
}
echo "Average: " . $sum;
```

Answer (score 0):

Lower school [math](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Average) says:

```
foreach ($textfill as $vote) {
    $sum += intval($vote);
}
$avg = $sum / count($textfill);
```

Answer (score 0):

The average value is calculated by divide the sum with the number of votes. This line will print the average value:

```
echo "Average: " . $sum/count($textfill);
```